# How to keep module exports from getting unwieldy

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, code-organization

Lets say I have the file structure:

```
- products
-- index.ts
-- fooProduct.ts
-- barProduct.ts
-- wootProduct.ts
```

In each "product" file, there are methods for getting the product `sku` and an object creator and possibly other stuff specific to the product.  This is for a react project so I'm avoiding classes as best practice state (this has been a tough transition for a classical OO person).

Example:

```
// products/fooProduct.ts
export interface FooProduct extends BaseProduct { //base defined in index
  //...
}

function getFooProductSku(){

}

function createFooProduct(){

}

function doFooStuff(){

}
```

In my index file, I'm exporting everything

```
// products/index.ts
export * from './fooProduct';
export * from './fooProduct';
export * from './fooProduct';
```

What I'm struggling with, is this results in a very FLAT mess of imports in my dependent files:

```
// dep-file.ts
import { FooProduct, createFooProduct, getFooProductSku, doFooStuff, 
         BarProduct, createBarProduct, getBarProductSku, 
         WootProduct, createWootProduct, getWootProductSku } from './products'
```

The above doesn't look horrible, but in practice with a much more complex domain it's getting unwieldy and hard to read.  I think the bigger issue is the only way to see which functions are tightly coupled, is through the naming convention (EG `Foo` prefix).

In an attempt to fix this, I've nested my methods in a exported object, so my class from above now looks like this:

```
export interface FooProduct extends BaseProduct { //base defined in index
  //...
}

export const fooProduct = {
  getProductSku: () => {

  },

  createProduct: () => {

  },

  doStuff: () => {

  }
}
```

This allows me to drop `Foo` from the function names and now the same dependent import now looks like this, regardless of what additional methods are added:

```
// dep-file.ts
import { FooProduct, fooProduct,
         BarProduct, barProduct,
         WootProduct, wootProduct } from './products'
```

I think this better accomplishes my goals, but I'm not convinced this is actually a good practice or wondering if there might be a better way to achieve a similar goal?

Comment: Why are you exporting everything from index?

Comment: @SLaks I saw that somewhere when I was first starting on this project.  Even if I don't, and instead import all the different functions from the different modules directly doesn't solve the issue.  It's not really the import statement that feels unwieldy, but more so just the functions being littered all over the code with no indication of what is tightly coupled (this issue might not be clear in my example due to the prefixes).  Maybe that's normal and I just need to get used to it.

Comment: updated to make the problem i'm trying to solve a little more clear

Answer (score 1):

```
// products/index.ts
import * as FooModule from './fooProduct';
import * as BarModule from './barProduct';
export { FooModule, BarModule };

// dep-file.ts
import { FooModule, BarModule } from './products';
type t = FooModule.FooProduct;
// Etc.  Change the names as desired.
```